# Gerrit try to configure trivial rebase

Tags: git, gerrit

I want to enable trivial rebase on gerrit 2.9.1. I followed documentation and changed labels.

Here what I hava in MY_PROJECT.git/config:

```
[label "Code-Review"]
    function = MaxWithBlock
    copyMinScore = true
    value = -2 Do not submit, I must review it !
    value = -1 I would prefer that you didn't submit this
    value =  0 No score
    value = +1 Looks good to me, but someone else must approve
    value = +2 Looks good to me, approved !
    copyAllScoresOnTrivialRebase = true
    copyAllScoresIfNoCodeChange = true
```

I restart gerrit, and when I look at my interface, labels didn't change and trivial rebase is not activated. Here's what I have on my interface:

```
Code-Review:
    +2 Looks good to me, approved
    +1 Looks good to me, but someone else must approve
    0 No score
    -1 I would prefer this is not merged as is
    -2 This shall not be merged
```

Any idea why it's not working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file to edit is 'project.config' in the All-Project repository.

See [this link](http://blog.bruin.sg/2013/04/how-to-edit-the-project-config-for-all-projects-in-gerrit/).

$ git clone ssh://user@gerrit.xxx.com:29418/All-Projects
  $ cd All-Projects
  $ git fetch origin refs/meta/config:refs/remotes/origin/meta/config
  $ git checkout meta/config
  $ #edit project.config
  $ git commit -a
  $ git push origin meta/config:meta/config